# Pareto optimal redistribution in binary exchange economy

Tags: economics, nash-equilibrium, utility

Consider binary exchange economy with two goods and two agents, whose preferences are defined as follows:

$\textbf{x}\succ  \textbf{y}$ iff $x_{1}x_{2}>0 $ and $y_{1}y_{2}=0 $.

In Edgeworth's box show individual rational redistributions, Pareto optimal and weakly Pareto optimal redistributions, if Initial endowment is $$ \omega = (\omega_1,\omega_2) =\left((2,8),(4,2)\right)$$

I draw Edgeworth box with endowment and indifference curve. But I do not know how to continue.

But I do not know how to continue. Any help?

Comment: That looks slightly peculiar.  It seems $(2,8)\not \succ (4,2)$ since $4\times 2 \not=0$ and $(4,2)\not \succ (2,8)$ since $2 \times 8 \not=0$,  and similarly with any distributions with both elements positive.  Is there really an indifference *curve*?

Comment: @Henry I thought that indifference curve for agent 2 is x and y axes and indifference curve for agent 1 is function y=1/x which lies within Edgeworth's box

Comment: But I see indifference between all distributions with $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$, and I would not call that a curve

Comment: @Henry can you draw some picture or elaborate the answer?

Comment: My problem is that I think the question has an error: it looks to me as if there are only two indifference sets: everything strictly inside the box is preferred to everything on the edge of the box, but apart from that nothing is preferred to anything else. So either I have misunderstood or there is nothing to do: the initial endowments seem Pareto optimal but so too does anything else with positive amounts for both, so there is no scope for strictly Pareto improvement once you are inside the box